# how can I align my WordPress website for mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I have created an e-commerce website [slvibe.com](https://slvibe.com). I was working properly but now when I open it on mobile devices it doesn't align properly. can you please help me.theme name storefront from woocommerce. the problem wasn't there before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this in a stylesheet : `*>body {padding-right: 205px; }`

which is killing the responsive design - I don't know why you would have that, but if you need it on the desktop version, then throw it into a media querie.

Note, it is inside a compiled stylesheet, so I don't know where it comes from - But it is being outputted in this file :
`/wp-content/litespeed/cssjs/6ec38.css`

Comment: thanks, it worked. the main problem was created by LiteSpeed cache plugin. my client just installed it and minifies all the css.